# Java Platforming Game Land on Platform

Tags: java, collision

My Collision code for platforms in my Player class isn't working and sometimes glitches out. I created different methods for applying gravity and whatnot.

When the player is under a platform and they jump, I want them to collide with the bottom of the platform and fall back down using the gravity method I created.

When the player walks into both ends of the platform I want them to just stop beside it.

I want to make sure at all times that the player cannot go through the platform and that seems to be my downfall.

I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me out.

Here is my Player class, the applet screen size is 600x400:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;


public class Player implements KeyListener
{
int x, y, width, height;

boolean jump, left, right;

PlayerThread playerThread;

int maxHeight = 40;
double heightC = 0;
boolean onPlatform = false;
boolean landed = true;
int prevY;

public Player()
{
    x = 500;
    y = 350;
    width = 40;
    height = 50;
    playerThread = new PlayerThread();
    playerThread.start();
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    String str = String.valueOf(x);
    String str2 = String.valueOf(y);

    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);

    g.drawString("X: " + str + ", Y: " + str2, 100, 100);
}

public void update(Platform p)
{
    CheckForCollision(p);
}

public void CheckForCollision(Platform p)
{
    int pX = p.getX();
    int pY = p.getY();
    int pWidth = p.getWidth();
    int pHeight = p.getHeight();

    //THIS IS COLLISION DETECTION CODE THAT DOES NOT WORK
    if (y + height > pY && y  < pY + pHeight && x + width > pX && x < pX + pWidth)
    {
        y = prevY;
        landed = true;
    }
}

public class PlayerThread extends Thread implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (left)
            {
                x -= 2;
            }

            if (right)
            {
                x += 2;
            }

            if (jump)
            {
                if (heightC >= maxHeight)
                {
                    System.out.println(heightC);
                    jump = false;
                    heightC = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    heightC += 1.5;
                    prevY = y;
                    y -= 5;
                    landed = false;
                }
            }

                            //GRAVITY CODE
            if (!jump)
            {
                if (y < 400 - height && !landed)
                {
                    prevY = y;
                    y += 5;
                    landed = false;
                }
            }

            if (y >= 400 - height)
            {
                y = 400 - height;
                landed = true;
            }

            try
            {
                sleep(17);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    switch (e.getKeyCode())
    {
    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
        left = true;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
        right = true;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
        if (landed)
        {
        jump = true;
        }
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{
    switch (e.getKeyCode())
    {
    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
        left = false;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
        right = false;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
        break;
    }
}



public int getX()
{
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x)
{
    this.x = x;
}

public int getY()
{
    return y;
}

public void setY(int y)
{
    this.y = y;
}

public int getWidth()
{
    return width;
}

public void setWidth(int width)
{
    this.width = width;
}

public int getHeight()
{
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(int height)
{
    this.height = height;
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: dude use a game engine, dealing with this sort of things is 10x easier

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with your detection code. I assume, you are using basic rectangle collisions, based on the if statement, however your clauses seem to be a bit strange.

Lets break them down:
`y + height > pY` - If the bottom of the player is below than the top of the platform.
`y  < pY + pHeight` - If the top of the player is above than the bottom of the platform
`x + width > pX` - If the right of the player is to the right of the left of the platform
`x  < pX + pWidth` - The the left of the player is to the left of the right of the platform

Now note the logic here: 
This will only trigger iff the player is *completly* inside the platform, which I expect is not what you want. What you probably want is more akin to a proof by negation:

```
if(!(y > pY + pHeight || y + height < pY || x > pX + pWidth || x + width < pX)){
    //There is a collision
}
```

On a side note, although I would generally agree with Mr. D and his comment of using a game engine, it is often useful from a learning perspective to know how these things work, so as you are not constrained to someone elses codebase.

Comment: Great answer, totally agree with the comment, developer has to know the basics

Comment: @Quirlion I know the basics, my first language was with C#.. I am just completely brain dead with all the crap I went through trying to figure this out. I still don't see how that code you gave me would allow the player to land on the top without glitching out or falling through, not allow the player to go thought it from below, not allow the player to go through it left or right..............!!!!!!